# Can't output hex in C++

Tags: c++, hex, bit

I'm trying to output a hex value assigned to a variable x and I can't seem to get it working in C++. I can do it in standard C but am getting undesired results in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned char x = 0xFF;
    printf("%X\n", x);
    cout << dec << x << endl;
    cout << hex << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
FF
\377
\377
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's `unsigned char`, the stream thinks you want to output a character, rather than its value.  Try casting to `int`

```
cout << hex << (int)x << endl;
```

You might also want to use `setw(2)` and `setfill('0')` stream modifiers to pad single-digit hex numbers to 2 digits (similar to using `%02X` with `printf`).